# Iframe file uploader submitting to new tab

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've browsed various other answers to this exact question, but I'm not able to resolve the issue, and I think I've followed every bit of advice I've found on there.

I'm working on a vanilla JavaScript application that needs to upload files via an Iframe. I'm creating the form and the iframe via JavaScript. The file uploader form is being triggered using JS `.submit()`, and the form has its target attribute set as the name and ID attribute of the iframe.

Despite this, the form opens up a new window once it's submitted.

Here is how I'm creating the form:

```
function newElement(elementType, elementID, elementClass, elementInnerText){
    let element = document.createElement(elementType);
    if(elementID != undefined){
        element.id = elementID;
    }
    if(elementClass != undefined){
        element.classList.add(elementClass);
    }
    if(elementInnerText != undefined){
        element.innerText = elementInnerText;
    }
    return element;
}

parentElement.appendChild(newElement('FORM','file-uploader','expense-details',undefined));

var fileUploadForm = formFieldWrapper.querySelector('form');
fileUploadForm.setAttribute('action', '/link/to/process.php');
fileUploadForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
fileUploadForm.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

fileUploadForm.appendChild(newElement('LABEL',undefined,'add-expense-form-field-label',undefined));
var formFieldLabel = formFieldWrapper.querySelector('label');

fileUploadForm.appendChild(newElement('INPUT',undefined,'add-expense-form-field',undefined));
var formField = formFieldWrapper.querySelector('input');
formField.setAttribute('type', 'file');
formField.setAttribute('name', 'expense_reference');

fileUploadForm.appendChild(newElement('INPUT','submit-file-upload-form',undefined,undefined));
var fileUploadSubmit = fileUploadForm.querySelector('#submit-file-upload-form');
fileUploadSubmit.setAttribute('style', 'display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px;');
fileUploadSubmit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
fileUploadSubmit.setAttribute('name', 'upload-file');

var iframeWrapper = newElement('IFRAME','iframe-uploader',undefined,undefined);
fileUploadForm.appendChild(iframeWrapper);
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'iframe-uploader');
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('name', 'iframe-uploader');
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('height', '150px');
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('width', '250px');
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('frameboarder', '0');
iframeWrapper.setAttribute('scrolling', 'yes');
fileUploadForm.setAttribute('target', 'iframe-uploader');
```

This is how the form renders in HTML:

```
<div id="form-field-1" class="expense-details-wrapper">
  <form id="file-uploader" class="expense-details" action="/link/to/process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe-uploader">
    <label class="add-expense-form-field-label">Expense Reference*</label>
    <input class="add-expense-form-field" type="file" name="expense_reference[]" placeholder="Expense Reference" required="true" multiple="false" accept=".jpg, .png, .pdf" priority="primary">
    <input id="submit-file-upload-form" style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px;"
      type="submit" name="upload-file">
    <iframe id="iframe-uploader" name="iframe-uploader" height="150px" width="250px" frameboarder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is how I'm submitting the form:

```
document.getElementById('file-uploader').submit();
```

I've also tried this:

```
document.getElementById('submit-file-upload-form').click();
```

I'm not sure why the form submits to a new tab. The PHP is obviously running fine, because the new tab shows me errors and success messages as I've set them up to be, but it doesn't post to the iframe as intended.

EDIT: Please disregard the `newElement` function I've included. I only created it function to expedite the writing process for new HTML elements, because I've created every part of the app's HTML interface with JS.

Comment: What is the relevance to "php"?

Comment: *"The PHP is obviously running fine"* - So this isn't a "php" question then. The tag should be removed, since it's misleading and makes the question unclear.

Comment: agreed. removing it now.

Comment: Thanks. `frameboarder` in your iframe. That should read as `frameborder`. I don't know if that makes a difference or not, but it still needs to read as that. I am not a JS guy, so I won't be of much help in that area. Edit: same for `setAttribute('frameboarder'`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue, but it did improve my code.

Comment: Can you show us the markup rendered for the target? It is likely the target does not exist when the JS runs the first time, so the target is not available when the click is performed. You may have to use event delegation.

Comment: I revisited the question to see if there was any progress. Did you try what @JayBlanchard mentioned in a comment?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm sorry, but could you please explain what I can provide you with a little more? I'm not able to understand what you mean.

Comment: Never mind, I see the rendered iframe. Because you render the iframe at the same time as you perform the AJAX call the targeted iframe does not exist, that is why a different tab opens. You will need to use [event delegation](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) to solve the issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sounds like an answer to moi ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you for the reference. However, I am not creating the iframe when the AJAX call is fired. The iframe is created as soon as the form is created, and the form's target attribute is set after the iframe appears in the DOM tree, after which, the event listener is added. The ajax call is performed when a button is clicked, and the button is created after the form and iframe are created. Does this influence your point of view?

Comment: To a degree, but I would need to test. Can you add statements to your JS to make sure the element exists before you make the AJAX call?

Comment: I just tried that. I added an event listener to the submit button for the form, and i had it console log the target iframe. It does that successfully.

Comment: I don't see that you're preventing the default action of the `click()`.

Comment: you're right. I did that just now by using <code>e.preventDefault();</code> on the submit button </code>click()</code>. The page does not reload anymore, but the form still does not submit to the iframe, and the image does not upload to the directory, which means the php file only loads when the new tab opens.

Comment: Did you examine the network tab after you did that? Was the data sent to the PHP script properly?

Comment: it actually appears to submit data to the iframe right when the iframe and form are loaded, before the trigger is even clicked. It does not submit data when the button is clicked.

Comment: At least we're headed in a direction.  I am jugginling conversations, let's go to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206086/discussion-between-jay-blanchard-and-syedmh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with @syedmh in chat it was determined the better way to go involves 2 things:

- Hard-coding the `iframe` in the page source solves the issue of targeting the frame, removing event delegation issues and,
- Switching to `formData()` would allow the OP top benefit from a more up-to-date technology for uploading files